# Manually set visited page with facebook analytics

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics

I'd like to switch from google analytics to facebook analytics and, within my app, at certain points I am manually setting the visited page like so:

```
    ga('set', 'page', 'MY-CUSTOM-PAGE');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour with the JS SDK for fb i.e.

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    **FB.someFunction('MY-CUSTOM-PAGE');**
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };



  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to manually set the visited page? A fb "page view" event should capture the current page, are you logging views as from a page that is not the currently loaded page?

Comment: @JonChurch It's inside a JS (ionic) mobile app where you don't actually navigate to pages. Yet, I want to track screen changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use the VIEWED_CONTENT event with the following parameters:

- CONTENT_TYPE: 'page'
- CONTENT is not used here
- CONTENT_ID: 'login' (For the login page in my app)
- price is 0
- CURRENCY is skipped

Example:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  var params = {};
  params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'page';
  // params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT] = contentData;
  params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT_ID] = 'login';
  // params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CURRENCY] = currency;
  FB.AppEvents.logEvent(FB.AppEvents.EventNames.VIEWED_CONTENT, 0, params);
}
```

In FB Analytics I can see now the following values in a log record (host was really localhost in this test):

- Event: fb_mobile_content_view
- Referer Domain: localhost
- Current URL: localhost
- fb_content_type: page
- fb_content_id: login